# kontact takes nearly a minute to start

Tags: release-juno, applications

I'm in the final stretch of completing a migration from lubuntu to elementary OS. One of my stumbling blocks was the transfer of Kontact. When I start Kontact, it takes 50 seconds before anything shows up on the screen.

It's like it's waiting for something else to start first, but I have no idea what.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm posting this both here and on the kde forum because I can't really tell if this is an issue with Kontact or elementary OS

Comment: Please open that app from terminal and look the debugging messages, that may help you find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who ever has this problem, the solution I stumbled upon was to use:

```
akonadictl fsck
```